# Meanings of defragmentation and when it is needed

Tags: filesystems, terminology, defragmentation

There seem to be two meanings of defragmentation:

- **Defragmentation** is a process that reduces the amount of fragmentation. Fragmentation occurs when the file system cannot or will not allocate enough contiguous space to store a complete file as a unit, but instead puts parts of it in gaps between other files.
- When under Windows, if we try to release existing free space from an NTFS partition (to later create a new partition especially during dual boot installation of Ubuntu besides an exisiting Windows OS), we will have to use Windows tools to move all the files to one end of the partition, and leave free space at the other end of the partition as much as possible. I heard this is also called **defragmentation**.

  Alternatively, Linux tools such as `gparted` can release free space from an ntfs partition without **defragmentation** (in the sense of the previous paragraph, not in the sense of the first paragraph) the NTFS partition first.

#### Questions:

1. I wonder if the two kinds of "defragmentation"  above
   always happen together?
2. Does whether a file system (e.g. NTFS) needs defragmentation depend on

   - the OS under which it has been used (e.g. Windows or Linux), or
   - the file system type (e.g. NTFS) itself?
3. Are the answers to questions in 2 different for different meanings of defragmentation (as mentioned earlier)? For example, I heard that,

   - in Linux, defragmentation in the first sense isn't needed on an EXT4 partition, unless a partition is occupied more than 90%, because Linux always try to automatically defragment.
   - Releasing free space from a NTFS partition by using the Linux tool `gparted` doesn't need to do defragmentation on the NTFS partition in the second sense, and is it because Linux always automatically move all the files to one end of the partition as much as possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can defragment the data stored on a filesystem (files, filesystem structures, metadata, etc.), the free space, or both.

Probably when someone just says "defragment", they mean the data (your first definition). Traditionally, when defragmenting the free space, it's put at the end (your second definition). Normally you'd only do this in preparation for shrinking a partition, but you could also do it e.g., to allow for a large contiguous allocation (say, you're about to edit some video). But really, except for shrinking a partition, free space defragmentation isn't often required.

Partition shrinking is generally only possible at one of the ends (most, if not all, partition formats[1] do not allow a hole cut in the middle). Typically filesystem data structures occupy the start of the partition, so shrinking (and growing) is normally done at the end. No matter which tool you use to do it (Windows disk manager, gparted, etc.), there must be enough free space at the end---and that often requires moving data. Both Windows and gparted will do that.

Whether a FS requires defragmentation depends on a lot of things, at least:

- What its used for. Random infrequently used documents can tolerate limitless fragmentation; pushing-the-limits DVR applications can not tolerate any. Some things are actually more tolerant of fragmentation than you'd think, e.g., databases (because they're usually doing random read/write, not sequential).
- What type of drive it is. Seeks on SSDs are almost free, so fragmentation is much cheaper.
- Amount of memory available for disk cache. Doesn't matter how fragmented it is on disk if its all reads and they're all satisfied from the cache. Or if all the writes can be buffered long enough to send them to the disk in order.
- OS, primarily due to caching differences.
- Filesystem. Some have a lot of overhead for very fragmented files.

The main problem with fragmentation is normally that it adds seeks to what could be a sequential read/write.

---

1: Though logical disk managers often do. E.g., when using sparse allocating, its typical to attempt to reclaim large-enough blocks of unused space. Note though that they pretend to the filesystem that the space hasn't been reclaimed (and give it back when the filesystem wants to write there).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is pretty worthless with their Fragmentation article...

Below we will address some why? and when? questions about fragmentation and defrag but without any details about specific FS.

... I also suggest a third option where frequently updated files (like logs) or even dir (like Downloads or /tmp) get extra spare space than absolute minimum.

E.g. preallocate space for big download (or with slow link). During sync, during transfer (e.g. from/to camera or phone), during copy (or backup or system update).

Pretty important topic.

If we place read-write F/D without extra free space close to older blocks, then WE enable fragmentation.

F/D without growth can be placed safely without extra free space. This includes read-only F/D... This also partially includes simple formats without compression (like BMP) when their resolution is known (like FullHD, 4K, 8K).

F/D only shrink (something very odd and special) - then you have actually useless gaps which you should defrag. This can happen when someone uses fast compression options (or capture format) and compresses them to the same directory - this depends if some program reuses F/D or not.

F/D to be deleted AS WHOLE - we can just erase them or remove records in filesystem without need for partial deletion and immediate defrag. We want to defrag such holes later.

One way to approach this kind of fragmentation is to track peak real size of F/D for each F/D or...  Even better way is to use more than one number, because peaks can be easily not representative (far from median). E.g. full system backup vs office work.

Another way is to track speed of growth. This is especially true for HDD. Fastest growers need fastest place on disk. But speed isn't the only factor: mission critical F/D, big customers, some emergency priorities, additional options for kill switch or just manually predict growth as admin without data in system.

Best way is to keep actual data about growth over relevant period of time and somehow predict what will happen with growth next (predicted data about growth) and only then make guess about predicted gap size (this value will be less relevant after prediction window).

Summary:

Only shrink - opinional defrag.

Never grow and never shrink - ...

Grow and shrink - be aware of gaps and expect defrag.

Not covered in this wiki: (de)fragmentation due to disk partitioning